# Rewrite query inside of loop in PDO format

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PDO and am currently trying to rewrite all of my queries. One query that I'm having trouble rewriting is this one because it's written inside of a loop:

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
$code = explode(" ", $search);
$code_count = count($code);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

if($search != "")
{
if($code_count == 1)
{
     $query .= " WHERE team LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."%'";
} elseif($code_count > 1)
{   
       for($j=0;$j<$code_count;$j++)
       {
        if($j != 0)
        {
        $query .= " OR "; 
        } else
        {
        $query .= " WHERE team LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($code[$j])."%' OR ";
        }           

                $query .= " team LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($code[$j])."%'";
    }

    $query .= "ORDER BY team ASC";
}
} else
{
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY team ASC";
}

$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
```

With PDO, I have tried the following.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

if($search != "")
{
if($code_count == 1)
{
     $query .= " WHERE team LIKE ?";

         $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
         $stmt->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->execute();
} elseif($code_count > 1)
{   
       for($j=0;$j<$code_count;$j++)
       {
        if($j != 0)
        {
        $query .= " OR "; 
        } else
        {
        $query .= " WHERE team LIKE ? OR ";
        }           

                $query .= " team LIKE ?";

               $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
               $stmt->bindValue(1, "%$code[$j]%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->execute();
    }

    $query .= "ORDER BY team ASC";
}
} else
{
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY team ASC";
}

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Not much luck with this method. I keep getting an error message reading: "nvalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Lance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bind parameters are named `1` to `n` when you don't assign a name yourself. You need to change this line:

```
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%$code[$j]%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

To this:

```
$stmt->bindValue($j + 1, "%" . $code[$j] . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since one can pass an array of parameters to [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) instead of binding each manually, one can *hugely* simplify the whole thing:

```
$code = explode(' ', $_GET['search']);

$stmt = $db->prepare('
  SELECT   *
  FROM     table
  WHERE    FALSE ' . str_repeat(' OR team LIKE ?', count($code)) . '
  ORDER BY team ASC
');

$stmt->execute($code);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have several errors in your rewrite:

- you are calling prepare / bind / execute several times during the construction of the query. You should call prepare just once, after your query string is fully constructed, and bind+execute after the query construction.
- in every iteration of your loop, you add one or two ( if j == 0) parameter to your query, but you try to bind just one per loop - so the numbers won't add up.

Generally, to use parametric queries, you need to follow the following structure:

1. build your query string
2. prepare your query string
3. every time you want to run your query:

   1. bind parameters
   2. execute
   3. fetch

So your code should be like:

```
// building query
if($search != "")
{
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM table ';
  if($code_count == 1)
  {
    // note: this if is unneccessary, the loop below would generate a good SQL even for code_count 0 or 1
    $query .= "WHERE team LIKE ?";

  } elseif($code_count > 1)
  {   
    for($j=0;$j<$code_count;$j++)
    {
      if($j != 0)
      {
        $query .= " OR "; 
      } else
      {
        $query .= " WHERE ";
      }           

      $query .= " team LIKE ? ";
    }

    $query .= "ORDER BY team ASC";
}
} else
{
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY team ASC";
}

// preparing

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);

// binding parameters
if($search != '' && $code_count >= 1) {
  for($j=0;$j<$code_count;$j++){
    $stmt->bindValue($j+1, "%".$code[$j]."%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
  }
}

// execute

$stmt->execute();

// fetch

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```